# Cassandra is Column oriented or key value store?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, key-value, column-oriented, wide-column-store

Cassandra is column oriented database as we know. But their is some discussions still going on on either is Key Value pair store or is column oriented database.

Please justify Cassandra is column oriented or key value pair store?

Answer (score 2):

Columns in Cassandra are an essential data modeling element. But as columns are stored based on a partition key, it's more a hybrid between a column-oriented and key-value store.